# Is the connection-org1.json missing in fabcar example?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The fabcar example in v1.4.2 on github.com now uses first-network as the underlying network. When I look into the enrollAdmin.js, it uses 'connection-org1.json' as the connection profile; however, I cannot find this file anywhere in the first-network folder or the fabcar folder. Is it missing?

The code in the enrollAdmin.json is (line 10):
const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'first-network', 'connection-org1.json');

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in tag v1.4.2 [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/v1.4.2/first-network/connection-org1.json)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just looking at the main branch, silly me.

Comment: That's fine, feel free to post your questions